# PHP session does not work

Tags: php, session, authentication

Hey guys I am new to PHP and trying to figure out how to implement $_session in a very basic login system:

```
<?php
session_start();

include 'dbconn.php'; 

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];


$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";


$result = $conn->query($sql);


$row = $result->fetch_object();

if($username == "$row->username" && $password == "$row->password") {

   $_SESSION['loggedin'] = "$username"; 

    header('Location: admin.php');

} else {

   header('Location: index.php?msg=wrong-username-or-password');

}
```

The problem is that when if I use local variables like:

```
$admin_userName = 'admin';
$admin_password = '1234';
```

and then making the comparison

```
if($username == "$adminusername" && $password == "$adminpassword") {

   $_SESSION['loggedin'] = "$username"; 

    header('Location: admin.php');
```

The $_session works perfect. But when I use this:

```
if($username == "$row->username" && $password == "$row->password") {

   $_SESSION['loggedin'] = "$username"; 

    header('Location: admin.php');
```

The session does not work. Without session the above statement works perfectly!

login.php

```
<?php
session_start();

include 'dbconn.php'; 

$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";

$result = $conn->query($sql);


$row = $result->fetch_object();

if($username == $row->username && $password == $row->password) {

$_SESSION['loggedin'] = $username; 
header('Location: apptify.php'); 
 } else {
     header('Location: index.php?msg=wrong-username-or-password'); 
 }
```

logout.php

```
<?php
session_start();
unset($_SESSION['loggedin']);

header('Location: index.php');
?>
```

I am really lost, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Keep in mind that you're comparing two different things. Are you sure you're even entering the condition? Are `$row->username` and `$row->password` set as you expect them to be?

Comment: They should be set up correctly and the condition should be correct as it works without $_session

Comment: Add an echo to the condition to make sure you're entering the condition.

Comment: You could try putting `if($username == "$row->username" && $password == "$row->password")` inside a `while` loop. Give that a go.

Comment: It crashes. It looks like the while loop didn't stop..

Comment: What about `if($username == {$row->username} && $password == {$row->password})` or `if(($username == {$row->username}) && ($password == {$row->password}))`

Comment: Did you put an echo statement in the if condition to make sure you were entering? You may also want to look at your error logs.

Comment: Yes it prints out (1)

Comment: [Did you try this?.....](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28987339/php-session-does-not-work#comment46224203_28987339)

Comment: gives syntax error Fred

Comment: We need to know the exact syntax error. I've tested your code with success.

Comment: I found what the problem is, and have posted an answer below. @M.El-Set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *The problem is that when if I use local variables like:
>
>   $admin_userName = 'admin';
>   $admin_password = '1234';
>   and then making the comparison
>   if($username == "$adminusername" && $password == "$adminpassword") {*

The problem is that, you're using:

```
$admin_userName = 'admin';
$admin_password = '1234';
```

then using:

```
if($username == "$adminusername" && $password == "$adminpassword")
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

You forgot the underscores and not matching the variables lettercase.

Variables are case-sensitive.

```
if($username == "$admin_userName" && $password == "$admin_password")
```

---

My test script, with success:

```
<?php
session_start();

$DB_HOST = 'xxx';
$DB_USER = 'xxx';
$DB_PASS = 'xxx';
$DB_NAME = 'xxx';

$con = new mysqli($DB_HOST, $DB_USER, $DB_PASS, $DB_NAME)  
       or die(mysqli_connect_error());

$_POST['username'] = "John";
$username = $_POST['username'];

$_POST['password'] = "Johnny";
$password = $_POST['password'];

$_SESSION['loggedin'] = "$username"; 

echo $username; // echo'd John

$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '$username'";

$result = $con->query($sql);

$row = $result->fetch_object();

 if($username == "$row->username" && $password == "$row->password") {

   $_SESSION['loggedin'] = "$username"; 

//    header('Location: admin.php');

echo "Match!";

} else {

//   header('Location: index.php?msg=wrong-username-or-password');

echo "No match.";

}
```

---

I need to point out that:

You should look into using [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements), *they're much safer*.

In regards to password storage.

If you're not already hashing passwords rather than what may be a plain text method you may be using, I suggest you look into [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) or PHP 5.5's [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function. For PHP < 5.5 use the [`password_hash() compatibility pack`](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Answer (score 0):

It should be without quotes:

```
if($username == $row->username && $password == $row->password) {

   $_SESSION['loggedin'] = $username; 
   header('Location: index.php');
}
```

Comment: Doesn't makes a difference here!

Comment: This does not solve the problem. Removing the quotes changes nothing.

Comment: I cant add comment upper, use "var_dump" and u should find problem.